# Field Strength Tensor as Commutator

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, curvature, commutator, yang-mills

I'm studying QFT and am confused on the field strength tensor for some quantum field. I've seen the tensor written as the commutator of the covariant derivative $$-igF_{\mu\nu}=[D_\mu, D_\nu].$$ Is this just a defined quantity that happens to give the lagrangian when summed over, or is there something deeper behind it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182612/2451

Comment: It just means that $F$ is the curvature of the gauge field.